# Play audio from stream

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a backend script that serves an audio file as stream. How do I serve play the file stream from a react frontend?

P.S. when I hit the URL from a browser, the audio element is automatically created the audio streams.

````
const cors = require('cors')
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express()
const port = 5000

app.get('/',cors(), function (req, res) {
    var file = './audio.mp3'
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(file)

    res.setHeader('Content-Type','audio/mpeg')

    stream.on("data",(chunk) => {
        console.log("streaming");
        res.write(chunk)
    })
    
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}))```
````

Comment: Just add media element and give to src your path.

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ thanks a lot man! So foolish of me to not think the simplest things first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ferhat I figured it out in a minute.
Stored the URL of the object in a state and wired it with an audio element.

```
state = {
    songUrl : ""
  }
  sendRequest = () => {
    
    this.setState({songUrl : "http://localhost:5000"})

  }

render(){
<audio src={this.state.songUrl} controls={this.state.songUrl===''?'':'visible'}/>
}
```